# How to return a sorted dictionary's keys by sorting its values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
a = {'str1':[int,int,int],'str2':[int,int]}
```

I want to returns the keys like  `['str1', 'str2']` because sum of sum(a[str1]) > sum(a[str2])

I tried to use the sum function:

```
return sorted(a.keys(), key = lambda a.values(): sum(a.values()))
```

But it raises an error.
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

How should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `sum(family.values())` will try to reduce a list of lists to a sum starting with the initial value 0. When you try to add a list to 0, you get a `TypeError` because the operation is not supported by either operand.

Try it like this instead:

```
sorted(family, key=lambda k: sum(family[k]))
```

The parameter for your lambda expression is `k`, and the arguments passed to it will be each element of the iterable, which is, in this case, `family.keys()` which can be shortened to `family` because dicts can be treated as iterables of their keysets. The value of each element's key will simply be the sum of the dictionary value which is a list.

Comment: The `.keys()` isn't strictly necessary, as iterating over a dictionary yields its keys by default.

Comment: If two people have an equal number of sum of value, they should appear in alphabetical order.  How to get that?

Comment: Before sorting by sum of values, sort by key: `sorted(sorted(family), key=lambda k: sum(family[k]))`